# SQL Server Query to group sequential dates

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table named Absence Details and I want to group sequential dates. Here, is the data

```
EID        AbsenceType  AbsenceStartDate               AbsenceEndDate
769     Holiday     2012-06-25  00:00:00.000            2012-06-25 23:59:59.000
769     Holiday     2012-06-26  00:00:00.000            2012-06-26 23:59:59.000
769     Holiday     2012-09-03  00:00:00.000            2012-09-03 23:59:59.000
769     Holiday     2012-09-04  00:00:00.000            2012-09-04 23:59:59.000
769     Holiday     2012-09-05  00:00:00.000            2012-09-05 23:59:59.000
769     Holiday     2012-09-06  00:00:00.000            2012-09-06 23:59:59.000
769     Holiday     2012-09-07  00:00:00.000            2012-09-07 23:59:59.000
```

The result i am trying to get is

```
EID     AbsenceType AbsenceStartDate          AbsenceEndDate
769     Holiday     2012-06-25  00:00:00.000         2012-06-26 23:59:59.000
769     Holiday     2012-09-03  00:00:00.000         2012-09-07 23:59:59.000
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to either remove AbsenceType column from header or add values for this column.

Comment: @ Vikdor - That's true i forgot to remove Absence Reason column. Thanks for that.

Comment: @podiluska - I haven't starting writing any query yet. Just looking for pointers.

Comment: Search for "Islands and Gaps"

Answer (score 4):

I have simplified your scenario to isolate the main problem. Let's supose this table with gaps:

```
with ns as (
select 1 as n union
select 2 as n union
select 3 as n union
select 8 as n union    --gap
select 9 as n )
select * 
into #ns
from ns;
```

Now, the result you are expecting for is:

```
ini fi 
--- -- 
1   3  
8   9
```

To get this results I massage the data in this way: first I create two views with start and end periods and second, I join both views to get final result. Notice that I join table with it self to locate starts and ends periods:

```
with 
inis as                                     -- identifying start periods
(
   select n1.n
   from #ns n1
   left outer join #ns n2 
       on n1.n = n2.n + 1
   where n2.n is null
   ),
fis as                                      -- identifying ends periods
( 
   select n1.n 
   from #ns n1
   left outer join #ns n2 
       on n1.n = n2.n - 1
   where n2.n is null
   )  
select inis.n as ini, min( fis.n ) as fi    -- joining starts and ends
from inis 
inner join fis 
  on inis.n <= fis.n
group by inis.n
;
```

You can transfer this technique to your data and data types. If you have any issue translating query be free to ask.

[Check query and results.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/80479?opt.textResults=true)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

```
SELECT EID, AbsenceType, MIN(AbsenceStartDate) AS AbsenceStartDate, MAX(AbsenceEndDate) AS AbsenceEndDate
FROM (SELECT EID, AbsenceType, AbsenceStartDate, AbsenceEndDate,
      DATEADD(dd, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EID, AbsenceType ORDER BY EID,AbsenceStartDate), AbsenceStartDate)
      FROM AbsenceDetails
      GROUP BY EID,AbsenceType,AbsenceStartDate,AbsenceEndDate
      ) a(EID, AbsenceType, AbsenceStartDate, AbsenceEndDate, Grp)
GROUP BY EID, AbsenceType, Grp;
```

Comment: +1 This is a very good answer. Next time remember to format the code

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as follows:

1. Identify the list of sequence of absence dates.

   ```
   SELECT
       ad1.EID, ad1.StartDate, ad2.EndDate
   FROM 
       AbsenceDetails ad1
       JOIN AbsenceDetails ad2
       ON ad1.EID = ad2.EID
   WHERE
       DATEDIFF(ss, ad1.EndDate, ad2.StartDate) = 1
   ```

   The results would be as follows:

   ```
   769 2012-06-25 00:00:00.000 2012-06-26 23:59:59.000
   769 2012-09-03 00:00:00.000 2012-09-04 23:59:59.000
   769 2012-09-04 00:00:00.000 2012-09-05 23:59:59.000
   769 2012-09-05 00:00:00.000 2012-09-06 23:59:59.000
   769 2012-09-06 00:00:00.000 2012-09-07 23:59:59.000
   ```
2. Iterate through the list and identify the start and end duration of each stretch. This is better done at the app layer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you want to find continuous time intervals in your records.
The main problem will be identifying what actually constitutes continuous time interval:
If you are looking at absence at work than any sequence of

```
date1.09:00 to date1.18:00  
date2.09:00 to date2.18:00
```

where `date2` is a **next business day** after `date1` can be considered continuous.

In your case it is relatively easy, but you will not be able to do it in a single query. At least I can't think of a way to do it right now.

P.S. "Islands and Gaps" algorithm suggested by "podiluska" will help you to write it in single query/stored procedure.